# Can't find bean in any scope Exception while running on websphere(WAS) 8.5

Tags: websphere

I am trying to deploy a web service on WAS 8.5 and i am getting the following exception in the server log while starting the application. This service was running on WAS 7 previously.

Does anyone have any idea about this ?

Thanks in advance.

```
[3/4/14 5:27:39:741 CST] 00000191 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.appedition/appCollectionTableLayout.jsp]: Initialization successful.
**[3/4/14 5:27:39:788 CST] 00000191 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause /secure/layouts/pagingLayout.jsp: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.appedition.AppEditionApplicationCollectionForm in any scope
    at** org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:695)
    at _ibmjsp.secure.layouts._pagingLayout._jspService(_pagingLayout.java:641)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:548)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1045)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:527)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(Unknown Source)
    at _ibmjsp.secure.layouts._vboxLayout._jspService(_vboxLayout.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:548)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1045)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:527)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(Unknown Source)
    at _ibmjsp.secure.layouts._contentLayout._jspService(_contentLayout.java:838)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:950)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:499)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:320)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1048)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:716)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:412)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1066)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.appedition.AppEditionApplicationCollectionForm in any scope
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.DefineTag.doEndTag(Unknown Source)
    at _ibmjsp.secure.layouts._pagingLayout._jspService(_pagingLayout.java:343)
    ... 101 more

[3/4/14 5:27:39:834 CST] 00000191 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\websphere\appserver\profiles\dmgr\logs\ffdc\dmgr_8300bef7_14.03.04_05.27.39.7888063670773023820718.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter 82
[3/4/14 5:27:39:975 CST] 00000191 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\websphere\appserver\profiles\dmgr\logs\ffdc\dmgr_8300bef7_14.03.04_05.27.39.834901919649726887194.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters -SER 1047
[3/4/14 5:27:59:834 CST] 00000191 MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=Direct_eaodr01,platform=proxy,node=eaodr01,version=8.5.0.2,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=eaodr01cell01,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated&#59; class=com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JerseyServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup&#40;Ljava/util/Set&#59;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext&#59;&#41;V, pc=0
[3/4/14 5:28:12:282 CST] 00000191 MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=Direct_eaodr01_1,platform=proxy,node=eaodr01,version=8.5.0.2,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=eaodr01cell01,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated&#59; class=com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JerseyServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup&#40;Ljava/util/Set&#59;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext&#59;&#41;V, pc=0
[3/4/14 5:35:05:090 CST] 000001b4 MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=Direct_eaodr01,platform=proxy,node=eaodr01,version=8.5.0.2,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=eaodr01cell01,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated&#59; class=com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JerseyServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup&#40;Ljava/util/Set&#59;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext&#59;&#41;V, pc=0
[3/4/14 5:35:18:974 CST] 000001b4 MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=Direct_eaodr01_1,platform=proxy,node=eaodr01,version=8.5.0.2,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=eaodr01cell01,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated&#59; class=com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JerseyServletContainerInitializer, method=onStartup&#40;Ljava/util/Set&#59;Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext&#59;&#41;V, pc=0
[3/4/14 5:45:36:314 CST] 0000675d servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/com.ibm.ws.console.environment/nodeCollection.jsp]: Initialization successful.
```

Comment: This looks like a product defect.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: You have application initialization error:[3/4/14 5:35:05:090 CST]   Failed to load webapp: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated&#59; class=com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/JerseyServletContainerInitializer,

Comment: TechNote from IBM Support: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011249

Comment: local class loader first(parent last) is the class loading configuration for this service. Is there anything i need to check before opening PMR ?   Thanks.

Comment: @AntonNovopashin . I dont have xmlbeans jar in my classpath.

Comment: Do you have JerseyServletContainerInitial‌​izer? How did you assemble your application? Did you look into deployed application directory to verify libraries?

Comment: I have jersey-server 1.9.1 jar which has JerseyServletContainerInitial‌​izer. Along with these i have jersey-core,jersey-client jars in my assembly. I have assembled it in .ear file. Do let me know if you need  any information. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error in Websphere 8.5.5.2 when trying to Update an EAR. During the update process in the WAS console, I went thru the steps too quickly and received an error telling me that the object is already loaded. I then did an uninstall/re-install of the EAR in question and after the install process was finished, I pressed start to activate the application, which resulted in an error message stating  "XXXX failed to start. Check the logs for server server1 on node SVRXXXXNode01 for details. An error occurred while starting XXXX. Check the logs for server server1 on node SVRGIAS1VMTNode01 for more information."

To fix this issue in the WAS console, go into the Websphere Applications/Websphere enterprise applications and press enter on the named application in question. Under references, select Shared library references. press enter in the check box to the left, where the module states "web" and your application is in the URI column. In the "available" box, select the "SHRLIB_vxxx" and press the arrow to the right of it to add the shared lib to the "Selected" box. Press OK, then OK again. Press Save to the Master configuration. You are now back in the Enterprise applications page. Select the app in question and press start.

This should fix the issue if you have a Websphere-based system, version 8.5.5.2.  Websphere version 7 did not have this issue, as it kept the shared library intact when installing an ear.